# Why does the type conversion take place without me telling it to do so when doing "character + 1"?

Tags: c++, ascii

When incrementing chars for example: `char character{'a'};` is `'a'` and as an INT is `97`. When I say "character + 1" or "a + 1" I will get the integer value `98` not `'b'`. Now if I do "++character" I will get the char 'b'.

```
char character{'a'};
cout << character + 1 << '\n';
cout << ++character << '\n';
```

Comment: Because `1` is of type `int`.

Comment: Conversion rules in C++ are crazy. @HongOoi There still will be a conversion even if you specify that both operands have `char` type like this: `character + char{1}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Addition and the increment operator are specified differently in terms of the types involved.

> **[expr.add]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#1) The additive operators + and - group left-to-right. The usual
>   arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type.

The usual arithmetic conversions turn every integral type smaller than an `int` into an `int`. There's no stopping it, it's baked into the language. And because those conversions happen before the addition itself, the result type cannot be smaller than `int`. And so `character + 1` is `int` that gets printed by the `operator<<(int)` overload of the standard stream class.

For increments, however:

> **[expr.pre.incr]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.pre.incr#1) The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1. The operand
>   shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an
>   arithmetic type other than cv bool, or a pointer to a
>   completely-defined object type. The result is the updated operand; it
>   is an lvalue, and it is a bit-field if the operand is a bit-field.

The result `++character` is of the same type as `character`, i.e. it remains a `char`. It's also an assignable expression (an lvalue) that refers to `character`. Assigning to it is the same as assigning to `character`. The result is therefore a `char` that gets printed by the `operator<<(char)` overload of the standard stream class.

Comment: I also searched where I can find something about " usual arithmetic conversions ". I searched the last C++ draft but was not able to find that topic.

Comment: Thanks! Got it now under http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/n4778.pdf "7.4  Usual arithmetic conversions [expr.arith.conv]". Seems to by a typo while searching ;) Thanks!